# Excel concatenation by using formula or vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two sheets in excel workbook. 
I need the formula which matches SITEID and concatenate 3 values to 1 separated by / .
I have tried to use **Vlookup** with ranges but not get the actual results.

First sheet contains (4 columns):

```
SiteId  Cell    Sector  Bore
MDLH1238    12381   1   10
MDLH1238    12382   2   20
MDLH1238    12383   3   40
MDLH1239    12391   1   60
MDLH1240    12401   1   50
MDLH1240    12402   2   20
```

Second sheet contains (2 columns):

```
SiteId  Bore
MDLH1238
MDLH1239
MDLH1240
```

The expected result should be like this :

```
SiteId  Bore
MDLH1238 10/20/30
MDLH1239 60 
MDLH1240 50/20
```

Comment: Match, then index the values off that, so match gets the row based on the ID, then index the range (col x,this row result).  Match and Index.

Comment: I don't think INDEX will be reliable, given that not all sites have 3 entries... You'll end up indexing into a different site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's only ever 3 sectors per site, and using your sheet names, and assuming your cells start in A1, enter these in Sheet2, adjacent to the SiteIDs:

Cell B2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)
```

Cell B3:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)
```

Cell B4:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)&"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)
```

That should produce content like:

```
SiteId    Bore
MDLH1238  10/20/40
MDLH1239  60/0/0
MDLH1240  50/20/0
```

That's got extra "/0" entries where the sector 2/3 don't exist, but the formulas get longer and harder to read, to do that.

Edit: Adds the formulas for dealing with "/0"

Cell B2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2),"")&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3),"")
```

Cell B3:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2),"")&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3),"")
```

Cell B4:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,1)&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,2),"")&IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3)>0,"/"&SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$7,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7,3),"")
```

Output:

```
SiteId    Bore
MDLH1238  10/20/40
MDLH1239  60
MDLH1240  50/20
```

Comment: Would the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) make things a little tidier? e.g. `=SUBSTITUTE(SUMIFS(D:D,A:A, G2,C:C, 1)&"/"&SUMIFS(D:D,A:A, G2,C:C, 2)&"/"&SUMIFS(D:D,A:A, G2,C:C, 3), "/0", "")` (needs worksheet names but you can get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to be able to do is to concatenate elements of an array using "/" as a separator. Unfortunately native Excel can't do this, but there are plenty of good VBA functions already written which will, e.g. the one described [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx).

So I would suggest this solution:-

```
=StringConcat("/",IF(Sheet1!A$2:A$7=A2,Sheet1!D$2:D$7,""))
```

starting in cell B2 of the second sheet and pulled down as necessary. This is an array formula and must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In order to use the StringConcat function, you need to copy the code from the web page, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>, select Insert|Module, then paste in the code.

[image]